# iOS >> Why can't I get to a UIView.layer.properties?

Tags: ios, uiview, properties, layer

I have a UIView in an .xib file connected to it's relevant .h file as an IBOutlet. I wish to set it's layer properties: borderColor, borderWidth and cornerRadius.

I did it once before and it was quite easy. It was something like:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
     self.myView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
     self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
}
```

For some reason, when I do it in this new project, these layer properties are not available. When I write "self.myView.layer." I get no options to fill.

Does anyone have any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: 4.something. The other project, where it's working fine, was done with the same XCode version.

Comment: @JamesWebster that's irrelevant.

Comment: Your autocomplete might be temporarily broken. Have you typed it completely to still ensure it works?

Comment: @H2CO3 Not if it's the indexing issue in older versions of XCode that stops autocomplete autocompleting.

Comment: @JamesWebster Then certainly, you would be right. :) But seeing the issues related to UIView's layer property, I was sure it was the header import that was missing (because it's an error I often encountered regarding new developers...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add QuartzCore framework to your project

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in your .h or .m file

Comment: Right... I actually did "//" on the #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> line in the project where it worked and it didn't give me any error in these code lines; so I assumed it wasn't the issue. But now it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your imports in order:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then it's possible this is a known indexing issue in older versions of XCode

Open the folder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete the folder that resembles your app name

Answer (score 0):

try this
1. Add QuartzCore framework to your project

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

2.

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     CALayer *myViewlayer = self.myView.layer;
     [myViewlayer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
     [myViewlayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
     [myViewlayer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

}
```